# how to get image name of the visible image of curlview in harism page curl example android?

Tags: android, page-curl

I have downloaded a demo which show page curl effect like a real book from https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl.Now I want to get the image name of the image which is visible to user, means the image which is not flipped. Can anybody tell me how can I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: at whihc place you need the name? Inside CurlActivity?

Comment: ok sushil I got the solution by mCurlView.getCurrentIndex(), thanks for your reply

Comment: great you solved it :)